# Get cumulative monthly users count based on user email

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query to get monthly cumulative user counts:

```
SELECT RTRIM(TO_CHAR(DATE_TRUNC('month', created_at), 'Month YYYY')) AS month,
       SUM(COUNT(id)::int) OVER (ORDER BY DATE_TRUNC('month', created_at)) AS total,
       SUM((email     like '%@domain%')::int) AS with_domain,
       SUM((email not like '%@domain%')::int) AS without_domain
FROM   users
GROUP  BY DATE_TRUNC('month', created_at)
ORDER  BY DATE_TRUNC('month', created_at);
```

The result is as follows:

```
[
  {"month"=>"October   2015", "total"=>2, "with_domain"=>1, "without_domain"=>1},
  {"month"=>"December  2015", "total"=>6, "with_domain"=>4, "without_domain"=>0},
  {"month"=>"January   2016", "total"=>13, "with_domain"=>4, "without_domain"=>3},
  {"month"=>"February  2016", "total"=>15, "with_domain"=>2, "without_domain"=>0},
  {"month"=>"March     2016", "total"=>36, "with_domain"=>15, "without_domain"=>6},
]
```

See, how `total` count is cumulative and others not?

I tried the following query:

```
SELECT RTRIM(TO_CHAR(DATE_TRUNC('month', created_at), 'Month YYYY')) AS month,
       SUM(COUNT(id)::int)                    OVER (ORDER BY DATE_TRUNC('month', created_at)) AS total,
       SUM((email     like '%@domain%')::int) OVER (ORDER BY DATE_TRUNC('month', created_at)) AS with_domain,
       SUM((email not like '%@domain%')::int) OVER (ORDER BY DATE_TRUNC('month', created_at)) AS without_domain
FROM   users
GROUP  BY DATE_TRUNC('month', created_at)
ORDER  BY DATE_TRUNC('month', created_at);
```

But it throws

```
column "users.email" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function LINE 3: SUM((email like '%@domain%')::int) OVER (ORDER BY... ^ : SELECT RTRI
```

And adding `email` to `GROUP BY` clause makes no sense at all...

How do I make all counts cumulative (like it's done with `total`)?

Expected result is like

```
[
  {"month"=>"October   2015", "total"=>2, "with_domain"=>1, "without_domain"=>1},
  {"month"=>"December  2015", "total"=>6, "with_domain"=>5, "without_domain"=>1},
  {"month"=>"January   2016", "total"=>13, "with_domain"=>9, "without_domain"=>4},
  {"month"=>"February  2016", "total"=>15, "with_domain"=>11, "without_domain"=>4},
  {"month"=>"March     2016", "total"=>36, "with_domain"=>26, "without_domain"=>10},
]
```

Comment: Your mistake is that you are trying to get the running total for `(email [not] like '%@domain%')::int` rather than for `SUM(email [not] like '%@domain%')::int)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just repeat the window clauses for each version you want accumulated:

```
SELECT RTRIM(TO_CHAR(DATE_TRUNC('month', created_at), 'Month YYYY')) AS month,
       SUM(COUNT(id)::int) OVER (ORDER BY DATE_TRUNC('month', created_at)) AS total,
       SUM(SUM((email     like '%@domain%')::int)) OVER (ORDER BY DATE_TRUNC('month', created_at)) AS with_domain,
       SUM(SUM((email not like '%@domain%')::int)) OVER (ORDER BY DATE_TRUNC('month', created_at)) AS without_domain
FROM users
GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('month', created_at)
ORDER BY DATE_TRUNC('month', created_at);
```

Comment: Could you, please, show me how to clean this up to not repeat `(ORDER BY DATE_TRUNC('month', created_at))` thrice?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko [you can name your window definition](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-WINDOW) & use the `OVER window_name` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Get the grouped counts per month first and then get the running sum.

```
SELECT month,
       SUM(total) OVER (ORDER BY month) as total,
       SUM(with_domain) OVER (ORDER BY month) AS with_domain,
       SUM(without_domain) OVER (ORDER BY month) AS without_domain
FROM   (SELECT RTRIM(TO_CHAR(DATE_TRUNC('month', created_at), 'Month YYYY')) AS month,
        COUNT(*) AS total,
        SUM((email     like '%@domain%')::int) AS with_domain,
        SUM((email not like '%@domain%')::int) AS without_domain
        FROM users
        GROUP BY RTRIM(TO_CHAR(DATE_TRUNC('month', created_at), 'Month YYYY'))
       ) t
ORDER  BY month;
```

Answer (score 0):

**rewritten based on OP comments**

use window functions with order for the rest aggs as well. also if you use same window, better taking it out of main part like here:

```
SELECT distinct RTRIM(TO_CHAR(DATE_TRUNC('month', created_at), 'Month YYYY')) AS month,
       SUM(COUNT(id)::int) OVER w AS total,
       SUM((email     like '%@domain%')::int)  OVER w AS with_domain,
       SUM((email not like '%@domain%')::int)  OVER w AS without_domain
       , DATE_TRUNC('month', created_at) --added for sorting
FROM   users
WINDOW W AS (PARTITION BY DATE_TRUNC('month', created_at) ORDER BY DATE_TRUNC('month', created_at))
ORDER  BY DATE_TRUNC('month', created_at);
```

Comment: I wrote in my question that I tried that and wrote an error I get. Please, go over the question again

Comment: my query is different - it has no group by. and you probably will want distinct

Comment: yes - it means you need the column you use for ordering to be selected as well. so you either remove `DATE_TRUNC('month', created_at)` from order or add it to column list

Comment: check my qry - I dont have `GROUP BY` at all - you must still use it from your error

Comment: Nope, I copypasted the query from your answer

Comment: oh yeah 0 I did not partition it :) - just a sec will update

Comment: This looks cool! But it still throws me `for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list LINE 7: ORDER BY DATE_TRUNC('month', created_at); /*blazer,user_id:... ^ : SELECT distinct RTRIM(TO_CHAR(DATE_T` :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143692/discussion-between-vao-tsun-and-andrey-deineko).